# Strange Chrome image resizing behaviour

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm having some weird behaviour with chrome regarding image resizing when the window is resized.

When Chrome is snapped fullscreen in Windows(double click the window to snap full screen), and I unsnap the window, causing it to revert to whatever previous size it was unsnapped, images are not being scaled properly.

For example, I have the following css code that resizes images to 100% height of the space available, and auto's the width:

```
img{
    height: 100%
    width: auto;
}
```

When the window is snapped fullscreen it looks fine, the aspect ratio's of the images are kept. But now if I unsnap the window (double click). The height will resize, the width will not, like below:
[image: Unsnap full screen in Chrome]

Whereas in Internet Explorer, unsnapping looks like this:
[image: Unsnapping fullscreen in IE]

Anyone know why chrome is not resizing properly? Or is there something wrong with my css?

If you need more code please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using normalize.css to make different browsers act more dependably?

Comment: If you manually adjust chromes window width after unsnapping does it fix the issue? Also, what does the width say when you view in developer tools (before and after)?

Comment: @aDroidman, Resizing the chrome window will not adjust the width of the images, just the height. I have to refresh the page for the images to resize correctly.

Comment: Can you inspect the image and tell me what CSS is being applied? Or if possible, to link us to the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use instead width:100% -> max-width:100%;

I had before this issue once, and I have used both properties of size

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

It works for me just fine, and save the proportion.